# Flash CS 5.5 resize radio button component

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, radio-button

How can I resize the radio button component that comes with Flash CS5.5?

The default look is quite small. The same applies to the radio button label which is also quite small.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can find the graphical assets in the library.   The folder will be `"Component Assets" -> "RadioButtonSkins"`.   Take note that there are many movie clips that comprise the various states of the radio button

As for the text/label portion of the radio button, you have to do that through code.  Here is an example function you could have:

```
function styleRadioButton(rb:RadioButton, myTextFormat:TextFormat):void {
    rb.setStyle("embedFonts", true); //if you want to use an embedded font
    rb.setStyle("textFormat", myTextFormat); //set the text format
    rb.setStyle("antiAliasType", AntiAliasType.ADVANCED); //if you want smoother looking fonts
    rb.textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT; //if you want the label to automatically grow
}
```

So if you have an instance of a checkbox called `myRadio`, you could do this:

```
var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 24, 0xFF0000); //make a red, 24px Arial text format
styleCheckBox(myRadio,textFormat);
```

---

Now, one easier thing you could also do is just place your radio button inside of a `MovieClip` or `Sprite` container and scale said container.  To do this:

1 - place an instance of a radio button on the stage

2 - with the newly made instance selected, press F8 (or Modify -> Convert To Symbol)

3 - Scale the newly made movie clip